# Any web interface to show deployments history with mcollective?

Tags: puppet, continuous-integration, glue-record, mcollective

I'm using mcollective & puppet for deployments.
I would like to know if there is any user interface which allows me to choose a specific package/version and deploy and any user interface i can already use which allows me to show the deployments history and their status.

(I saw that glu has a nice user interface i'm looking for something like it, http://linkedin.github.com/glu/docs/latest/html/tutorial.html

)

I wondered if i could use glu (so that i can get their deployment history gui if they have a good one...) with mcollective but from what i understand they are parallel frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [KermIT](http://kermit.fr/).